# Text got all messed up (misaligned) in the footer

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, joomla-3.5

Now all of a sudden I have a weird issue.
For some reason, in the footer where you see 4 columns (those are all
Custom HTML modules in Joomla) - HELPFUL LINKS, NEWSLETTER, CONTACT US and
BUSINESS HOURS, under NEWSLETTER and BUSINESS HOURS the text is misaligned
and I can't get it back to normal. Tried to re-create the text in the
module. Doesn't help. Have no clue what that could be!
I'm attaching a print screen so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

in file `/templates/jp-x2/css/custom.css`
add following selector:

> .bottom-d-outer p {
>   margin: 0 0 9px;
>   }